# jquery call the iframe document ready after parent load completed

Tags: jquery

In my parent window there are few tabs shown.
On parent Window I think there is something code of click but I am unable to access or view the PARENT page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').click(function(){
        // Do something. Show/Hide tab panel according to tabs
    });
})
```

On the I frame window

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Add new tab in the parent window from I frame.
   $("#ParentTab", parent.document).after('<a href="#" class=".tab" tabid="newtab">New Tab</a>');
   // Add the panel in parent window for this new tab
   $("#ParentTabPanel", parent.document).after('<div tabid="newtab">Some Content</div>');
})
```

This code works fine and not showing any js error. The iframe content is load successfully and added the tabs on the parent window. But when I click on the NewTab it doesn't show the tabpanel. Strange when I ctrl+refresh the browser it works.

I will not work when first time load why? Please help me to solve this issue.
Copy the parent tab click event to new added tab. Is it possible? how to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your new tabs are added dynamically and will NOT have the event handlers set.

You can register the handler on the document object instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.tab' ,function(){
// Do something. Show/Hide tab panel according to tabs
});
})
```

It is possible that the children's 'ready' event fires after parent window's 'ready' event. Making the first page load not working.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response. Basically I am unable to see ready event of the tabs on parent window. They are coming from third party tool. I added a custom tab isside.

Comment: can I copy the click event of parent tab to new added tab?

Comment: you don't need to, my answer register the click handler to the docuemnt object, and will be effective to all .tab s

Comment: I don't have permission to access the parent window.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem. You'd better update your question about this. it is important restriction.